# Git fetch: How to keep on my local branch?

Tags: git

I was reading this post: [What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

and it said that once you do a "git fetch", you actually update your "remote-tracking branches under refs/remotes//".

If so, let's say that I have a branch named 'dev_branch' and it exists both on my local machine and on the remote server. If I do "git fetch", can I say that:

1. No change will be made to local branch 'dev_branch' ?
2. The branch 'origin/dev_branch' will be updated as the branch in remote server?
3. If I do "git pull", I understand that it merges my local branch with the remote one. If I just opened a local branch that doesn't have a correspondent branch in remote server (let's call it my_branch), how will "git pull" affect it? Is it correct to say that it will not cause any change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For question 1 and 2. Yes, you are right. In case of

> git fetch

There will be no change in your local **dev_branch**, git will only synchronize **origin/dev_branch** in your local computer with its counterpart in remote repository. This behaviour of **git fetch** is described clearly [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches). One way to verify this behaviour is by comparing:

> git diff origin/dev_branch dev_branch

For question 3, if there is no **origin/my_branch** in remote repository and you invoke

> git pull

Git will prompt error:

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
>   remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

You can specify the remote branch, you'd like to merge change with you local **my_branch** by:

> git pull remote_repository remote_branch_name

And run **git log** to see the effect:

> Merge branch 'remote_branch_name' of git_on_the_cloud_service/remote_repository